# AMCharts V3 Vertical Guide ValueAxes

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Is there any way to add a vertical guide to an AMCharts graph, but have it tied to the vertical `valueAxis` rather than the `categoryAxis`?

I cannot connect the guide to the CategoryAxis because I need the guide to represent a threshold on an arbitrary property of the categories that I have represented as a curve on one of the `valueAxes`. Looking at this mockup, imagine that the dashed line represents the `guide`.

[image]

Imagine the category axis of "Books" and the first value axis of "Popularity" with data ordered from highest to lowest.

Imagine the curve I plotted in blue is a cumulative RRP of the books (which may be represented by some bars not pictured in this example, for instance) which is tied to a second value axis. The dashed guide line would be a useful representation of a maximum budget in this scenario to see which books you would prioritise buying within this budget based on their popularity.

Answer (score 0):

`guides` are attached to the axis they're drawn on if the `guides` property is set at the axis level, i.e.

```
"valueAxes": [{
  "guides": [{
    "value": 100, // horitonzal line
    // ...
  }, {
     "category": "some category", //not valid. no line
     // ...
  }],
  //...
}]
```

so you can't draw a vertical guide on a valueAxis guide in your case. You can have multiple guides (it *is* an array, afterall), so I'm not exactly sure why you can't attach it to the categoryAxis along with your other guide.

You can also specify the `guides` array at the top level of the chart configuration and they'll draw on the appropriate axes, depending on which properties you're using (`value`, `date`, `category` and the `to*` variants if the guide is supposed to illustrate a range), i.e.

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "guides": [{
    "value": 100, //drawn horizontally
    // ...
  }, {
    "category": "some category", //drawn vertically
    // ...
  }, {
    "value": 300,
    "category": "a different category", //drawn both horizontally and vertically. only works on a top level guide, not an axis-level guide
    // ...
  }],
  // ...
});
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/e58e0fdc09fd912986887c0e3029267a?editors=0010)

Comment: I've added an example scenario to the question that might help illustrate what I'm, trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't follow why the category axis guide wouldn't work - you're marking a vertical dashed line that marks off the popular books. You have the plot that line somewhere on that axis. Does the vertical line need to start and start beneath the curve? A [trendline](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/TrendLine) would be more appropriate in that case.